# Delete specific document in Mongodb with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

i am new in mongodb. i want to delete a specific document from collection, but it can not deleted while there is no any syntax error.

**Here is show_post.php**

```
<?php
    $connect = new Mongoclient();
    $db = $connect -> post;

<table width="50%" border="1">
  <tr>


    <th>#</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>description</th>
    <th colspan="2">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php $result = $db->blogs->find();?>
    <?php  foreach ($result as  $row) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["_id"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></td>

        <td><a href="delete_post.php?id=<?php echo $row['_id'] ?>">Delete</a></td>
        <td>  <a href="edit_post.php?id=<?php echo $row['_id'] ?>">Update</a></td>

      </tr>
      <?php endforeach?>

</table>
```

**and here is delete_post.php**

```
         $id=$_GET['id'];
         $var = array("_id"=>$id);

         $del =$db->blogs->remove($var);
          if(!$del){

          echo "not deleted";
          }else {
          header("location:show_post.php");
           exit();
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: try querying your ID and see what ID you are passing to delete function. Remember,  if you try to delete an object that doesnt exist, mongoDB do not throw any exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are passing a string representation of the `_id` to `find()` method:

```
<td><a href="delete_post.php?id=<?php echo $row['_id'] ?>">Delete</a></td>
```

Since MongoDB PHP version >=1.0.0, the `find()` should return [MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php) object. If you `echo` this variable it returns the string representation.

What you could do is to convert it back as object by:

```
$var = array("_id"=>new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id));
```